# Tension in a chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

A chain of $n$ links of mass $m$ is being pulled upwards by a force $F$.

Trying to study this system, here are my questions and thoughts:

1. Each link accelerates at a rate $\frac{F}{nm}$ (?)
2. What are the forces on each link? There is the mass of the link as well as the masses below it, but what about tension? It seems that tension acts upwards on each link, is this correct? Is there any tension due to the link below it?
3. If this is correct what about the top chain, is there no tension acting on it at all? Only the force $F$ and the weight of the entire chain below it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To study the system you need a free-body diagram first. See the example below, where I name each link 1,2,3.. up to $n$ starting from the top. The force upwards where the chain is pulled is designated $F_0$ for consistency since the forces between successive links are designated $F_i$.

[image: fig1]

The crude diagram of a single link on the right describes all the forces acting on this link. The pulling force from the previous link is $F_{i-1}$ and the reaction from the next link is $F_i$. Newton's 3rd law applies here, as $F_i$ is applied in a positive fashion on link $i-1$, and in a negative fashion on link $i$.

The weight of each link is $\tfrac{m}{n} g$ where $m$ is the total chain mass and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity.

Also, each link might accelerate with a magnitude of $a_i$, but since all links are connected for this scenario all accelerations are equal to $a$

$$a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_i = \ldots = a$$

The next step is to apply Newton's 2nd law and write

$$ F_{i-1} - F_i - \tfrac{m}{n} g = \tfrac{m}{n} a $$

or

$$F_i = F_{i-1} - \tfrac{m}{n} (g+a) = F_0 - i \tfrac{m}{n} (g+a) $$

We know the two boundary conditions for the forces $F_0 = F$ is given, and $F_n = 0$ as the bottom link is free.

This means that on the last link

$$ F_n = F_0 +n \tfrac{m}{n} (a+g) = 0 $$

or

$$ \boxed{ a= \frac{F_0 -m g}{m} }$$

Now we can back substitute into the equations of motion to get

$$ F_i = F_{i-1} - \tfrac{1}{n} F_0 $$

or

| Link | Force |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $F_1 = F_0 - \tfrac{1}{n} F_0$ |
| $2$ | $F_2 = F_0 - \tfrac{2}{n} F_0$ |
| $3$ | $F_3 = F_0 - \tfrac{3}{n} F_0$ |
| ... | ... |
| $i$ | $F_i = F_0 - \tfrac{i}{n} F_0$ |

Answer (score 0):

If the chain is rigid then all links must accelerate upwards at the same rate - let's call this $a$. If we initially consider the chain as a whole then there are two external forces acting on the chain - the upwards force $F$ and its weight $nmg$ (here I am assuming that the mass of each individual link is $m$, although the wording of the question is ambiguous). So we have

$F - nmg = nma
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow a = \frac F {nm} - g$

Considering each link separately, then there are three forces acting on most links - the upwards tension from the link above, the downwards tension from the link below, and the weight of the link itself $mg$. Note that we do not need to worry about the weight of the links below this one, because that is taken care of in the downwards tension exerted by the link below. The two exceptions to this are the top link, where there is the upwards force $F$ but no upwards tension, and the bottom link, which has no downwards tension.

Let's call the downwards tension on the $k$th link from the bottom $T_{dk}$ and the upwards tension on the same link $T_{uk}$.

Starting with the bottom link, we have

$T_{u1} - mg = ma
\\ \Rightarrow T_{u1} = m(g+a)$

For the next to bottom link we have

$T_{u2} - T_{d2} - mg = ma$

But we know from Newton's 3rd law of motion that that $T_{d2} = T_{u1}$, so

$T_{u2} - m(g+a) - mg = ma
\\ \Rightarrow T_{u2} = 2m(g+a)$

Continuing up the chain like this, you can calculate the tension between each link and the link above it, until you get to the top link. You should find that the tension between each pair of links increases linearly from bottom to top.